# The script works from the sheet, but not as addon with the same code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

The project is published as a Sheets add-on. A trusted tester (also a spreadsheet editor) launches an add-on and it does not work. He receives the message "You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask the owner of this item to grant access to you".
If the editor starts the built-in script in the same spreadsheet with the same code, then everything works.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sName = ss.getName();
var eds = ss.getEditors();
var owner = eds[0];
var ed = eds[1];
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Task");
var emailAddress = owner.getEmail();
var subject = "Done! - " + sName;
var localDate = Date();
sheet.getRange(12, 2, 1, 1).setValue(localDate);
var values = sheet.getRange("B2:K11").getValues();
var message = "#" + values + "#" + localDate + "#";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
ss.removeEditor(ed);
```

Please advise where to dig.

Comment: do the error come from `MailApp.sendEmail()` ?

Comment: That error almost certainly arises from the line that modifies the spreadsheet's list of editors.

Comment: @JSmith I deleted lines from remEditor.js:
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
Changed the version number in manifest.json.
Packed again in a zip archive and uploaded to the store.
I checked if the editor's version of the add-on was updated - yes, it was updated.
The editor launched the addon and got the same error.

Comment: @tehhowch After that I deleted the lines:
    ss.removeEditor(ed);
    sheet.getRange (12, 2, 1, 1).setValue(localDate);
and repeated all the manipulations.
The editor launched the addon and got the same error again.
So it's not about active operations with the sheet and rights?

Comment: @BorisBaublys sorry try this `try{/*yourCode;*/} catch(e){Browser.msgBox(e.message + " line: " + e.lineNumber)})

Comment: @JSmith I wrapped my code in try...catch, as you suggested, and it all worked! MsgBox did not show up, but the add-on performed all the functions: it inserted the current date, sent the letter, revoked the rights of the editor.
I do not understand what was the matter. Do you have any guesswork?
Anyway, thank you.
Answer the question and I will mark it.

Comment: @BorisBaublys done just answered your question by the way if it worked then it's normal msgBox doens't trigger. really weird.

Comment: @JSmith Sorry I understood why it worked. In the spreadsheet, which the rights are granted to the editor, the code is embedded, and the name of the function in it is the same as in the add-on. Thus, the editor, pressing the button, launched the function not from the add-on, but from the built-in script.
So the question is still open.

Comment: @BorisBaublys did msgBox showed when the editor had an error?

Comment: @JSmith no, only red message "You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask the owner of this item to grant access to you".

Comment: @BorisBaublys is it the only code you have or are there more?

Comment: @JSmith There is no another code in the spreadsheet (It was, but I deleted it, so as not to be confused). Button assigned script from add-on.
I changed now the publication of the add-on - did not for trusted testers, but by the link - the error remained in place.

Comment: @JSmith Question along the way: I look at the manifest.json, for some reason the container ID is indicated there. This is normal? I created an addon based on the unbound script.

Comment: @BorisBaublys sorry cannot help you with that I've done a manifest file once but it was long time ago.

Comment: If the question is open, you might wanna unaccept the answer and  [Edit] your question to add all your comments and your effort so far. Provide [mcve].

Comment: Please elaborate on how your tester "launches the add-on". Provide  complete code.

Comment: @I'-'I I assigned script (remEditor) to button on the sheet. Here is a [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-editor/nclaodbgfbblobfhhmgknapgpkkljabe) to the addon, the full code is in the description.

Comment: @I'-'I You are right, the question is open. I hurried to rejoice. If the correct answer appears, I will accept it. If it does not, let it be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a add-on doesn't grant all permissions to the add-on.  It also needs to be enabled. Published add-ons run in `AuthMode.NONE` unless enabled. Try  adding a menu item and running the function there first to enable it in the document.

- [Add-on Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization#editor_add-on_authorization)

Comment: Thank you! I already checked installed/enabled and tried the menu option in my worksheet. However, for the purity of the experiment, I did the same thing again with the newly created document. [That's what happened](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_4yRxm9Yo6fXL5DsbuzINDbgw4Edw9EEOrgj0l16iQc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Boris `onOpen` code should be in the add-on... The menu items should come under Addons main menu....

Comment: Oh, that's what's the matter! Do I have to call the addon function from the menu? Thanks for pointing out my mistake. But I wanted not to using the menu. On mobiles the menu is less convenient than the button. The button can be made very large, but I don’t know how to change the size of the menu.
According to your advice, I created a new addon - added to the code onInstall, onOpen, createAddonMenu. Here is a [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-editor-v-2/egkdgppledgjkibhajmoeomhklbkbmlc) to the addon, a complete code - in the description.
It works, thanks again!

Comment: And yet, maybe there is a way to run the add-on code from the button? The menu and sidebar on mobile are less convenient than the button.
There is another disadvantage for the user. Despite the fact that he is an editor, he needs to re-install the addon, although it has already been installed by the owner.
Can this be avoided?

Comment: And yet, before that, I made changes to the addon like this: I changed the code in remEditor.js and the version number in manifest.json, archived the package and downloaded the zip file to Chrome Store.
So it is possible? Everything else in the manifest does not change, if you update the editor via Script?
I had to do so, because I have not found a way to set the version number of the type 0.0.0.1 in Version Management in the Script Editor. It only numbers 1, 2, etc.
Also in Script editor there is no manifest.json, instead appsscript.json is there ...
Sorry for a bunch of questions :-)

Comment: @Boris Hi... It's better to ask a different question. "How to make a add-on function from a button?" . Mobiles don't support buttons, menu or dialogs. So, most of your concerns are pointless. They only support onEdit() triggers. Or You need to write a separate android add-on.

Comment: Hi I followed your advice, thank you, and asked a separate question [How to start a add-on function from a button on a sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617769/how-to-start-a-add-on-function-from-a-button-on-a-sheet). I would appreciate your ideas on this.

Comment: @Boris I have nothing much to add than the above comment. I asked you to post a new question for broader audience and views.  One last thing I  would like to add is that, I would leverage the onEdit function for mobile. Create a datavalidation drop down in a cell instead of a button(say  option `✔️`,`❌` with increased font size say,72). If the option changes, you'd get a onEdit trigger fired. I honestly don't think anyone is going to go to desktop view on Chrome mobile, unless they have no other choice (They have a app). Installing app is more comfortable than visiting desktop mode in mobile.