# How to run a add-on function from a button on a sheet?

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I made an addon ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-editor-v-2/egkdgppledgjkibhajmoeomhklbkbmlc), in the description - the full code) that works like this.
The spreadsheet editor fills the cells and selects the item to which the addon script is assigned in the user menu. The script inserts the current date on the sheet, collects the cell values, sends them to the owner, and removes the editor’s access to the spreadsheet.

Everything works great on the desktop, but does not work on mobiles. Now more than 50% of users visit the Internet from mobile devices. Mobile users cannot access menus, sidebars and buttons in the Google Sheets application. In addition, the mobile application must be additionally downloaded and installed. It is not comfortable.
In the mobile browser (for example, Chrome) they are available, but only if you select "Full version" in the settings.
In addition, in Chrome, the menu items are very small, you have to swiping to increase them. This is all uncomfortable.

It would be great if you could launch the addon from the button. The button can be made large. Then on mobile devices, using the spreadsheet directly in the browser will be more convenient.

Are there any ways that can solve this problem?
I would be grateful for the ideas.

Comment: See [Develop Android Add-ons for Google Docs and Sheets](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/mobile/)